# Can't rerender apex:commandButton when it is in apex:pageBlockButtons component

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

As a title says I can't rerender commandButton when it is in pageCommandButtons component. In this case it is rerendered:

```
<apex:commandButton id="sendEmailButton" value="{!$Label.SendEmail}" action = "{!sendEmail}" disabled="{!isSendEmailButtonDisabled}"/>   
<apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.New}" reRender= "viewNew" action = "{!show}"/>              
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

And in this case isn't:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.New}" reRender= "viewNew" action = "{!show}"/> 
        <apex:commandButton id="sendEmailButton" value="{!$Label.SendEmail}" action = "{!sendEmail}" disabled="{!isSendEmailButtonDisabled}"/>   
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried rerendering the entire pageBlockButtons component? In general with reRender, you start small, and work your way to bigger and bigger pieces of the UI. So I'd try slapping an `id` on the pageBlockButtons and point to that to rerender.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: It is something wrong with pageBlockButtons. It blocks rerendering feature in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Since I just ran into this myself... put an `apex:outputPanel` inside the `apex:pageBlockButtons` and put the `apex:commandButton`s inside that. Now you can rerender the `apex:outputPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try wrapping the pageblockbuttons in an `<apex:outputPanel>` and rerender the panel

Comment: Yes, but it's not work due to the rule <apex:pageBlock> must be the direct parent of <apex:pageBlockButtons>.